# Create a Node.js Express project in intelliJ

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, express

I have nodejs plugin installed in intelliJ, but I could not find a way to create a Node.js Express project, as [what can be done with WebStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/04/web-projects-templates/). See the screenshot of WebStorm below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This feature will be available in IntelliJ IDEA **11.1.3** version. 11.1.2 version was released before this feature appeared in WebStorm.

See the [related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85027) in IDEA YouTrack project.