# How to use the Intellij Node.js plugin with PyCharm?

Tags: node.js, pycharm

I'm running PyCharm 3.0 commercial and I'm trying to install the [Node.js plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098?pr=) (which is supposed to work with PyCharm). I've followed the [several](http://mykola.bilokonsky.net/2012/02/using-intellij-idea-to-build-html5-apps-on-a-node-js-server/) [different](http://www.denizoguz.com/2013/03/28/html5-development-with-intellij/) directions to install the plugin but after I successfully install the plugin and restart PyCharm nothing appears next to the help button (as the install instructions say they should happen) and nothing referencing Node appears in Settings -> Javascript.

I am using the commercial version so [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625565/nodejs-plugin-in-intellij-community-edition-does-not-work) isn't the problem.

I'm using the newest version so [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770904/create-a-node-js-express-project-in-intellij) shouldn't be a problem.

I'm on MacOSX 10.8

Comment: Can you create a new project as an express project?

Comment: **1)** `Settings | Plugins` -- do you see node.js plugin listed there and it is enabled? **2)** Node.js plugin is a standard plugin and easiest way to install it is to use `Settings | Plugins | Install JetBrains plugin...` button, no need to download anything from a plugins website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NodeJS icon was removed from the toolbar in PyCharm 3.0 as NodeJS isn't a primary instrument for Python developers. It only about visual presentation. Node.js settings can be found in `Settings | JavaScript | Node.js`.

Comment: Found it thanks! I was looking at the Javascript tab, not the Node.js subtab. Doh!